# Connection Error io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception: HTTP/2 client preface string missing or corrupt. Hex dump for received bytes:

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

Working on Grpc Bidirectional Streaming, when i try to run grpc, getting below error

```
Connection Error
io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception: HTTP/2 client preface string missing or corrupt. Hex dump for received bytes: at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception.connectionError(Http2Exception.java:82)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$PrefaceDecoder.readClientPrefaceString(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:322)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$PrefaceDecoder.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:263)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:445)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeLast(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:382)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:286)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.channelInactive(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:421)
    at io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler.channelInactive(NettyServerHandler.java:227)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelInactiveNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:56)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelInactive(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:92)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:135)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:928)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$7.run(AbstractChannel.java:674)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:339)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:356)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:742)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: You got your answer, why don't you show some appreciation by accepting it?

Answer (score 39):

One thing to be aware of there is the difference between the default behavior of `NettyServerBuilder` and `ManagedChannelBuilder` w/r/t plaintext.

If you don't enable TLS on the server (eg, by calling `sslContext()` or `useTransportSecurity()` on the server builder), then you *must* call `ManagedChannelBuilder.usePlaintext(true)` on any channel connecting to the server.

So, in other words, a server is fine defaulting to plaintext, but for channels you need to call `usePlaintext()` to allow communication with plaintext servers.  If not, you'll get this exact `HTTP/2 client preface string missing or corrupt` exception (although, in my case, with a particular string of bytes following the hexdump).

Answer (score 10):

The client and server aren't agreeing. Typically this is because one is plaintext and the other using TLS. But it can also be due to HTTP/1 vs HTTP/2 in certain environments.

The `Hex dump for received bytes` is empty though, so there's not enough information to diagnose the issue more precisely. I've never seen the bytes be empty when seeing this failure though.

Comment: I see this is an older answer, but I ran into something similar and am quite stuck. Do you have any ideas? I am following these two answers but no luck: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70311138/http-2-client-preface-string-missing-or-corrupt-for-c-client-grpc-using-nanopb

Is there a way to create a plaintext channel using C (Arduino project)?

Comment: This clued in on my issue on Postman. I had used a gRPC connection which worked, then copied that connection inside of Postman. Once I did that and I tried hitting a local gRPC connection, it had this issue. I had to create a new request from scratch, then it worked.

Comment: 'one is plaintext and the other using TLS' - that was a thing in my case. Good diagnosis!

Answer (score 0):

While running the service locally, we need to disable TLS.